# Search and replace with regex letters outside of html tags and '

Tags: php, regex

I have this PHP code:

```
$subject = "word1 <a skip this word2 >w'aot'rd2 again</a> word3";
$pattern = "~<[^>]*>|'[^>]*'(*SKIP)(*F)|o~";
$replace = 'O';
$result  = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $subject);

echo $result;
```

It's works fine when I replace "o" for "O" outside of HTML tags , but I search don't replace the "o" inside of '' as well.

And I need replace array of letters, like "r" for "R" and "a" for "A".

Result find: "`wOrD1 <a skip this word2 >w'aot'rD2 again</a> wOrD3`" Replace "o" for "O" and "d" for "D", outside of tags html and outside of ''.

Comment: what is the expected result you are looking for?

Comment: i search this: "wOrD1 <a skip this word2 >w'aot'rD2 again</a> wOrD3"

Replace o for O and d for D, outside of tags html and outside of ''

Comment: You need to group the "skip fail" part: `(?:<[^>]*>|'[^>]*')(*SKIP)(*F)|o` https://regex101.com/r/lY8pU3/1 . You could also use the `x` modifier to add some spacing and comments [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lY8pU3/2)

Comment: your regex will quickly fail for any HTML comments containing  "`>`" / "`<`" inside or for example the same in attribute values. Replacing text outside of HTML tags works best by applying the regex operation on text-nodes in a DOMDocument..

Comment: @user3341848: Please do not add phrases like Help me Pls / Regards. This is just a question, not writing an email nor a forum post.

Comment: Thanks HamZa! and for array replace? a for A and d for D?

Comment: @user3341848 use `\w` instead of `o` and `preg_replace_callback()` with something like `strtoupper()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [PHP code](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_php_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMMTdlclZ2b1E3ckU) to turn only "o" and "d" to upper case:

```
$str = "word1 <a skip this word2 >w'aot'rd2 'word5' word6 'word7'</a> word3";
$re = "~(?:<[^>]*>|'[^']*')(*SKIP)(*F)|([od])~";
$str = preg_replace_callback(
    $re,
    function ($matches) {
        return strtoupper($matches[1]);
  },
  $str
);
echo $str;
```

If you want to add more, just define your own range. Say, `[a-z]` for all English characters.

Output:

```
wOrD1 <a skip this word2 >w'aot'rD2 'word5' wOrD6 'word7'</a> wOrD3
```

Comment: @Hamza: Thanks, I did not notice when editing my former reply :)

Comment: Welcome. Could you change the demo link? Also avoid the use of link shortener.

Comment: @HamZa: Changed. Actually, I thought I could only use shortened links on TutorialsPoint. I see I was wrong.

Comment: I believe you need to change the `'[^>]*'` alternative to `'[^']*'`.  To see why, change the text that's between the tags to `'word4' word5 'word6'`.  If I'm reading the question right, it should change `word5` to `wOrD5`, but it doesn't.

Comment: @AlanMoore: I have just been checking this regex, and yes, I also was looking at that place in it. Thank you for a hint!